# c# File.ReadAllLines doesn't read blank lines

Tags: c#, file

I am using c# for reading some txt documents and writing/deleting some lines in them
I have to read a text document, delete some of it's lines and then save it again in the same path.
It worked all good until I realized that it doesn't read empty lines or when there is just a space in a new line :(.

Here's my text file structure:

```
-Name
-LastName
-Age
-Phone
-Address
-Address2(optional) -// this line will be deleted
-Address3(optional) -// this line will be deleted
****here comes the empty line****
```

Here's my code:

```
        List<string> myLines = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
        
        if (myLines.Count > 5)
        {
            for(int i = 7; i >= 5; i--)
            {
                myLines.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(path, myLines.ToArray());
        }
```

So I don't know why when I run File.ReadAllLines will give me 7 lines (ignoring the blank one) and  of course after I delete something in the file, the blank line is still there.

Note: I am working with more than 100k files, either way I would just delete that specific line by hand.

Can you help me sort this out and delete that blank line? Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear. There are no empty lines in the example you posted. Your code doesn't check for "empty" lines either, it tries to "remove" the 6th and 7th line. You can't remove items from an array. This code won't compile

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I mentioned that ` "here comes the empty line"`. And my code deletes the line I want to delete since it can't read the empty line, so if I add from 8 to 5 it will give an error.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Arrays have no `.RemoveAt`, that's a method of the `ArrayList` or `List` classes. And there are no empty lines in the example you posted. `-(here come the empty line)` isn't a empty line. Neither is `*here's come the empty line`

Comment: *c# File.ReadAllLines doesn't read blank lines* - it really does, honest

Comment: @panagiotisKanavos, I declared a list, I read from a list, I remove from a list and return an  array.

Comment: @CaiusJard well it's either that I am lying here or I don't know much about that function reading blank lines. Since I don't have a reason for the first one, can you help me clear my confusion with the second one, honest?

Comment: And yet your code shows `string[] lines`. Post your *actual* code and an *actual example string*. Right now, it's far more likely that you're mistaking newlines and empty lines than any bug in `ReadAllLines` that was never discovered by millions of .NET developers for 20 years. That method is pretty simple. It doesn't affect the contents in any way.

Comment: Your RemoveAt presumably returns a changes object and does not change the original array/list/enumerable you have. Check that method.

Comment: Okay, let me edit my question again.

Comment: Post real code that actually reproduces the problem. It's actually very easy. Create a verbatim literal with the content you want, eg `var sample = @" ....";` and write it to a file with `File.WriteAllText`. Verbatim literals can cross lines. After that post real code that reads that file and produces a result. Then post that result and what you expected

Comment: I just edited my question with the actual code. I have literally working with this piece of code for a month now. I was able to read, delete and rewrite on a file for a hundreds of times. I just noticed that I have a blank line in the text file and I have to get rid of it.

Comment: Is it really an empty line (just a newline), or did the last "filled" line end on a newline - giving the *impression* of an empty extra line? (where "newline" is the appropriate end-of-line sequence)

Comment: I guess it is a matter of how you see that newline sequence : as a line *terminator* or as a line *separator*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
    var f = @"-Name
-LastName
-Age
-Phone
-Address
-Address2(optional) -// this line will be deleted
-Address3(optional) -// this line will be deleted

-Name2";

    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\a.txt", f);

    var f2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\a.txt").ToList();

    f2.RemoveAt(7);
    f2.RemoveAt(6);
    f2.RemoveAt(5);

    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\b.txt", f2);
```

Open the two resulting files a.txt and b.txt in c:\temp (make sure you have a c:\temp) - the a has blank lines, the b has no interim blank lines or address2/3

[image]

..but do note that b has a blank line at the end, because `File.WriteAllLines` will end the final line (Name2 in my example) with a CRLF.

If this is what you're talking about/you don't want, consider something else instead, perhaps:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\b.txt", string.Join(Environment.NewLine, f2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. That's what I'm trying to say. With my code the removing part of blank lines or any line works perfectly. But it still leaves that blank line in the end. I want to get rid of it.

Comment: See the trailing part of the answer.. If your files are huge (multi megabytes), let me know and I'll propose an alternative, because doing string.Join has to allocate a single string to write

Comment: No actually this was all I was trying to achieve. Thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated.